# how do you summarize factors in data frame every 5 minutes

Tags: r

```
 dput(d)
structure(list(TimeStamp = structure(c(1459569739, 1459569739, 
1459569739, 1459569739, 1459569739, 1459569739), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Status = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("get", "send"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("TimeStamp", 
"Status"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is a subset of a big data set. I need count the status column for every 5 minutes. Status could be send or get. I need to count it status every 5 minutes.

I have tried something like this:

```
agg<- aggregate(data["Status"], list(fiveMin=cut(data$TimeStamp, "5 mins")),sum)
```

it is complaining about not able to count the factors. Is there any other way?

Comment: How are you planning to sum values such as "get" and "send"? How much is "get" + "send"? Try `aggregate(d["Status"], list(fiveMin=cut(d$TimeStamp, "5 mins")), length)` maybe

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I need to count of get and send differently

Comment: Try `library(data.table) ; dcast(setDT(d), cut(TimeStamp, "5 mins") ~ Status, length)`

Answer (score 1):

If you need this for every interval and desire the zero counts for some intervals, you may need to `merge` this with a vector with the interval boundaries that you desire using the `seq` generic that also has a POSIXt method allowing an interval specification with `by="5 min"`. With the example offered, we only see a single time point so the result is not particularly rich:

```
> tapply(d$Status, cut(d$TimeStamp, breaks="5 min"), function(x) sum(x=="get") )
2016-04-01 21:02:00 
                  5
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to simply convert to a wide format, here's a `data.table` example

```
library(data.table) 
dcast(setDT(d), cut(TimeStamp, "5 mins") ~ Status, length)
#              TimeStamp get send
# 1: 2016-04-02 07:02:00   5    1
```